# Recursive Insertion Sort Help Requried - Python

Tags: python, recursion, insertion-sort

I have been stuck on this problem for quite awhile now. I am just learning how to code and recursive statements just do not make much sense to me. In my programming class, I was told to make a recursive insertion sort program, and I did, but it will not be accepted because I do not know what the function is doing and how it is changing the list so that it is sorted. So I have two questions that I'll address separately with pretty much the exact same code.

The first question I have about my code is, as mentioned before, how does it work?

```
numList = [2,4,1,3,5]
def insertionSort(i, numList):
    if i > 0:
        insertionSort(i-1, numList)
        if numList[i] < numList[i-1]:
            numList[i], numList[i-1] = numList[i-1],numList[i]
            insertionSort(i-1, numList)


insertionSort(4,numList)
print(numList)
```

I'm calling the function twice and I have no clue why that works. I would think the call the the function before the if statement would have it work, but it does not.

And that leads me into my other question.
How would I make this code:

```
numList = [2,4,1,3,5]
def insertionSort(i, numList):
    if i > 0:
        insertionSort(i-1, numList)
        if numList[i] < numList[i-1]:
            numList[i], numList[i-1] = numList[i-1],numList[i]



insertionSort(4,numList)
print(numList)
```

work?

My professor said that the code is basically there but there is something that I need to either change or add in order for it to work correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: I feel like this is more algorithmic and oriented to computer science theory rather than programming. Try Computer Science Stack Exchange.

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/39912/755.  This violates site rules.  @MalikBrahimi, if you are going to suggest another StackExchange site, in the future, please make sure to mention not to cross-post and suggest that they can click "flag" to flag it for moderator attention and ask the moderators to migrate it.  (Also: be careful with your site recommendations.  [Questions about programming or implementations are off-topic for CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so this question isn't appropriate for CS.SE in its current form.)

Comment: @MalikBrahimi This is about debugging a program, so it's off-topic on [cs.se] but fine for SO.